# opencv: First cvtColor is much slower on different machine

Tags: c++, opencv, hardware

After gaining some experience with opencv, I recently installed it on some server with a strong graphic card to benefit from cuda functions. However, I did some tests with "normal" opencv and realised that it seems to run much slower even though the server is supposed to have better hardware. Here is a little code I wrote to investigate the matter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;



int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    const clock_t begin_time = clock();

    Mat OneRBG,OneGray,TwoRBG,TwoGray,ThreeRBG,ThreeGray;

    OneRBG=imread("./image.jpg");
cout << float( clock () - begin_time ) /  CLOCKS_PER_SEC <<"After imread One"<<endl;
    cvtColor(OneRBG, OneGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cout << float( clock () - begin_time ) /  CLOCKS_PER_SEC <<"After cvtColor One"<<endl;
    TwoRBG=imread("./image.jpg");
cout << float( clock () - begin_time ) /  CLOCKS_PER_SEC <<"After imread Two"<<endl;
    cvtColor(TwoRBG, TwoGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cout << float( clock () - begin_time ) /  CLOCKS_PER_SEC <<"After cvtColor Two"<<endl;
    ThreeRBG=imread("./image.jpg");
cout << float( clock () - begin_time ) /  CLOCKS_PER_SEC <<"After imread Three"<<endl;
    cvtColor(ThreeRBG, ThreeGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cout << float( clock () - begin_time ) /  CLOCKS_PER_SEC <<"After cvtColor Three"<<endl;
}
```

As you can see, I load some picture three times and convert it to grayscales while printing out the time that each step took. If I do it on a linux that runs on a parallel machine on some mac mini, here is what I get:

```
0.015641 After imread One
0.020779 After cvtColor One
0.038313 After imread Two
0.041601 After cvtColor Two
0.074171 After imread Three
0.076574 After cvtColor Three
```

Nice and fine, no surprises here. However, when I run the very same code on the aforementioned server, which also has Ubunutu 16.04, it says

```
0.010095 After imread One
0.577088 After cvtColor One
0.584784 After imread Two
0.586759 After cvtColor Two
0.594362 After imread Three
0.596315 After cvtColor Three
```

The absolute times differ due to the different hardware, of course, but as you can see, the first cvtColor takes an awful lot more time than any other one. I am sure someone here is wise enough to exlain to me why that would be the case.
What might be even more interesting, though, is that my other computer does not show that kind of behavior and if there is a way to make my server behave the same, you can bet I'd be keen to hear it.

Thanks in advance for any answer and have a nice day

Comment: One suggestion for your tests...you shouldn't rely on the benchmark of a single run; instead, you should run a for loop for a large number of trials and take the average or similar statistical measure. Is it possible that the compiler knows that you're reading the same image so it optimizes it? Perhaps delete each `Mat` after each run? Maybe create deep copies of the image *first* and run `cvtColor` speed tests on those.

Answer (score 3):

I did some further research and found something interesting:
http://answers.opencv.org/question/123990/why-is-the-first-opencv-api-call-so-slow/

I wished I had found it before bothering you all, but I think it solves the problem. Maybe it is as valleymanbs says and this setting has been made on machine 1 from the start. Further investigation would be, indeed, necessary, but I think from here on I can go on alone.

One last thing, in case someone finds this question and happily copies the lines given in the link above, I think he made a little spelling error in the header. At least for me it should be written as

```
...
#include <opencv2/core/ocl.hpp>
....

cv::ocl::setUseOpenCL(false);
```

Thanks to everyone for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You could check for any "strange" (e.g. machine specific) compilation flag, both when you compiled OpenCV and when you compile your code: it could be that on the first machine the compiler is doing optimizations that can't work on the second one...